# Rails: Reference to new Model throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise

I have a working users table.
I have generated a new table using:

```
rails generate model quiz_answers
```

..and run rake db:migrate

My CreateQuizAnswers migration file looks like this:

```
class CreateQuizAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quiz_answers do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.string :answer1
      t.string :answer2
      t.string :answer3
      t.string :answer4
      t.string :answer5
      t.string :answer6
      t.string :answer7
      t.string :answer8

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have a quiz_answer model:

```
class QuizAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and a QuizAnswersController:

```
class QuizAnswersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = current_user
        @quiz_answer = current_user.quiz_answer.build
    end

    private 

    def post_params
        params.require(:quiz_answer).permit(:body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

I have added :quiz_answers as a resource in routes.rb

**Edited question:**

**WHY, then, when I try to build a form (using Devise) do I get the error "undefined method `body' for...(with a reference to QuizAnswer here)"? I have another model 'Post' which does not generate this error and does not have a 'body' attribute.**

The page where I'm trying to build the form is home/whattypeofleader.html.erb and, in routes.rb I have:

```
get "whattypeofleader" => "home#whattypeofleader"
```

And in my HomeController I have:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def whattypeofleader
        @user = current_user
        @quiz_answer = current_user.quiz_answer.build
    end
end
```

What the HELL am I doing wrong? Any help desperately appreciated, thanks.

Oh, and in case you need it, here's the form code, a partial that gets 'rendered' in whattypeofleader:

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @quiz_answer]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :autofocus => true , :class => "elearning-input"%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit("Save entry") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you add has_many association in user model?

Comment: I have has_many :quiz_answers in user.rb

Comment: @moosefetcher then you want `current_user.quiz_answers.build` - pluralised

Comment: Model should be named `QuizAnswer`, not `QuizAnswers`

Comment: @moosefetcher Model names are always singular by convention

Comment: OK, thanks for the comments I will amend the question as it's a different error now...

Comment: QuizAnswer doesn't have a body attribute looking at your table

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Would you mind explaining what that means? I have another model called Post, which works fine, using very similar Devise form code (including the :body ref) and it does not have a body attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @quiz_answer]) do |f| %>
  #...   
  <%= f.text_area :body, :autofocus => true , :class => "elearning-input"%>
```

You are creating a text_area here, and you tell rails to bind this text area input with a `@quiz_answer.body` attribute. Why?

`form_for` assigns last element of an array to be a form's object. It yield a form builder object (`f`), which keeps a reference to this object (`f.object`). All the fields created with this form builder are automatically populated with a value of `f.object.send(:field_name)` (it also set up a name of the fields, so the params can be easily matched when it is posted). This is rails magic making all the form fields populated with model's data.

Since your model does not have `body` attribute (no such column in your database and no method with that name defined), `f.object.send(:body)` throws a `method undefined` error.

Regarding the fix to that, you need to decide how this form is to look for. Your models contain 8 columns, `answer<i>` (which is worrying and suggests you might wanna use association here).

Comment: I have copied this form code from the working version I have using 'posts'. I was using f.text_area just as a test, since it works in the 'posts' case. I understand that f is a FormBuider - I fully understand OOP. I want to understand the alleged rails 'magic'. Why does 'post' have access to :body (despite not having a body attribute) and 'quiz_question' doesn't? Why is it 'worrying' that my table contains 8 columns? PLEASE explain - I'm getting to the end of my tether with this. Thanks.

Comment: @moosefetcher - Why do you say that `posts` has no body attribute? Could you post your schema for posts table as well as posts model?

Comment: OK - 'post' has a body attribute defined in the migration file, which is news to me. Thank you for pointing me to that file. I think I need to ask a new question now re: how the quiz_answers table should work. Thanks again.

Comment: @moosefetcher - It is hard for me to tell, as I don't know what it is responsible for. However, every time I see a long list of columns named `sth_<i>` I feel that sth is wrong - it will likely cause you a lot of duplications in your code or some weird meta-loops, which will make your code less readable. Cold you tell me what those columns (answer1, answer2, etc) really represents?

Comment: I want quiz_answers to store a user's answers to the 8 questions in a quiz. I had been thinking of storing them in a serialized array but I was also told this was bad practise. I've felt like a rails noob for about 2 months now and it's getting very frustrating.

Comment: @moosefetcher - Believe me I know the feeling, when I started rails I hated it for half a year before I got it. TBH, I would prefer serialized array than 8 columns, but it is not an ideal solution either. The problem with current approach is that if you add another question to your quiz you will need to write a new migration - this is not very flexible. With serialized array it is not an issue, but it makes it harder to get all the answers for given question. I would most likely revisit quiz models a little bit, it would be best to do this over the chat (hpefully the option will show up soon)

Comment: I've asked another question about this, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177465/building-multi-choice-questions-with-devise-formbuilder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62402/discussion-between-broisatse-and-moosefetcher).